# Dedicated GPU memory of ryzen 5 5500u

Tags: memory, performance, gpu

I have a HP laptop (16GB DDR4 RAM) which has Ryzen 5 5500u processor (integrated GPU).

When I go to task manager, under performance section it shows the dedicated GPU memory is only 512 MB and the shared GPU memory is 7.7 GB.

I found somewhere that the GPU memory of this processor is 2GB.

##### Is there anything wrong? Can I increase my dedicated GPU memory from 512MB to 2GB?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For an APU (integrated graphics) there is little difference between dedicated RAM and shared RAM in terms of performance for *most* situations.

Dedicated RAM for an APU is memory that is permanently blocked off from your system RAM as opposed to being allocated as needed. Depending on the game increasing it *can* increase performance if the game is already allocating a lot of system RAM for the game itself, in which case you can lose some system RAM to VRAM to gain a small amount of graphics performance. GTA V is apparently a game that benefits from this on systems like the Steam Deck which are similarly limited.

You will need to boot into your BIOS menu. On Windows 10/11 the instructions are

> How to boot into UEFI or BIOS from Windows 11 or Windows 10
>
> 1. Click Start and then select Settings.
> 2. Click Update & Security.
> 3. On the left side, click Recovery.
> 4. Under Advanced start-up, click Restart Now.
> 5. Click Troubleshoot.
> 6. Click Advanced options.
> 7. Select UEFI Firmware Settings.

Then look for a "GFX" or Graphics menu. If your system is adjustable you should see a "UMA Frame Buffer" option. Some laptop manufacturers lock this option down so it is not guaranteed to be available.

There are a couple of videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jwrWCF5fhc) that suggest that if your laptop *is* locked then a tool called [UniversalAMDFormBrowser](https://github.com/DavidS95/Smokeless_UMAF) that can browse and adjust settings not made available to the standard BIOS for your laptop, but it's use can potentially brick your system so you should exercise caution.